# How to declare an array type that can contain either a string or other array?

Tags: typescript

Here is the variable declaration with type any:

```
let errorMessagesBag: any = []
```

erroMessagesBag must be able to hold a variable number of values that can be either a string, or a tuple of strings.
Example

```
let errorMessagesBag = ["string1", ["tuplestring1", "otherString"], "string2"] // and so on
```

How to replace 'any' with proper type declaration in this case, so it accepts an array that contains  strings OR a tuples of strings  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [union types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
let errorMessagesBag: (string | string[])[] = []
```

or

```
let errorMessagesBag: Array<string | string[]> = []
```

The two syntaxes are equivalent.

Comment: Nice. I wonder how one would reference such a variable without typescript complaining, eg:
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.
I can specify using (<string[]>myArrayOfStrings).map(...), but that feels dirty somehow.
What's the 'correct' way?

Comment: @MaxWaterman I suggest to convert the string to an array of strings: `const strOrArr: string | string[] = ""; (typeof strOrArr === "string" ? [strOrArr] : strOrArr).map(item => "...")`. But if you you have another question, it is best to create a question.

Answer (score 5):

Just to extend correct answers - with a global custom **`type`** declaration:

```
type stringTypes = (string | string[]);
let errorMessagesBag: stringTypes[] = []
```

Comment: Thanks. Then when to use an interface over a global custom type ? Are they equivalent ?

Comment: `type` could by used globally. Just create some project related .d.ts file, and place it there. From that moment, you can use it anywhere - treated as a global type. The same (move it to global .d.ts.) we can do with `interface`, but these are for different stuff. They are describing structure of the object (its API), methods, properties etc. So, both `type` and `interface` are there for us, but do different stuff, while could be defined very similar way.. hope it helps a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 const a: Array<string|string[]> = ["string1", ["tuplestring1", "otherString"], "string2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since typescript 3.7 you can create a general recoursive type:

```
type Tree<T> = T | Array<Tree<T>>
```

And then use it like this:

```
let errorMessagesBag: Tree<string> = ["string1", ["tuplestring1", "otherString"], "string2"];
```